# Probability of moving from the top node to the bottom node.

Tags: probability, graph-theory

[[image: The graphs <span class=]$G_N$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR3CY.jpg)

> Consider the set of graph $G_N$ for an interger $N\geq2$, shown above. Suppose a random walker starts at the top node of graph $G_N$ and begins a random walk where any route out of a node is equally probable. Find the probability, as a function of $N$, that the walker reaches the bottom node before returning to the top node.

I initially tried to think about this by braching out and counting probabilities, but soon realised that the walker can just go on forever. I tried to think about this using recurrence equations for the middle two points. Something along the line of letting $x$ be the chance to get to the bottom node from this vertex and $y$ for the other vertex. So for the top middle point, there's a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance it does up top, and $\frac{2}{3}$ it does to the $y$ vertex and use whatever chabce that has for $x=\frac13\cdot0+\frac23\cdot y$ I'm unsure how to go from here, however.

I believe the answer should to be $\frac{2n}{3n-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we ignore the direct paths from the top node to the bottom node and try to figure out the probabilities $q_j$ of reaching the bottom node without returning to the top node when we start at node $j$, we know that those probabilities form an eigenvector $(q_1\;\dots\;q_{2n})^T$ associated with the eigenvalue $1$ of the transition matrix (with top and bottom absorbing). We also know that $q_1 = 0$, because we cannot reach the bottom node without returning to the top node if we are already at the top node. We know that $q_{2n} = 1,$ because it is certain that we reach the bottom node when we are already at that node.

Such an eigenvector is uniquely defined by the properties mentioned above and can be found with some linear algebra and/or some trial and error:

Start with $0$, accumulate $2$s and $1$s in alternating order until you have $2n$ numbers (including the $0$ at the beginning). In the end, divide all the intermediate results by the sum of the $2$s and $1$s. Example: $n=4:$ Accumulating $2,1,2,1,2,1,2$ results in $0,2,3,5,6,8,9,11.$ Now divide by $11$ and you get $\frac{0}{11},\frac{2}{11},\frac{3}{11},\frac{5}{11},\frac{6}{11},\frac{8}{11},\frac{9}{11},\frac{11}{11}$. The $j$-th of those numbers is the probability of reaching the bottom node without returning to the top node when we start at node $j.$

We can see that the probability to get from the second node to the bottom node without returning to the top node is $\frac{2}{S}$, where $S$ is the sum of the accumulated $2$s and $1$s. It is easy to show that $S=3n-1$.

Therefore, the overall probability (honoring the direct paths) is
$$
p = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{S} 
= \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{3n-1} 
= \frac{6n-2+2}{3(3n-1)}
= \frac{2n}{3n-1}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I do get the answer $\frac{2n}{3n-1}$ for $n=2,3,\dots, 10$ calculating with the following Sage-code:

```
def solve(n):
    matN = 2*n
    A = 1/3*matrix(QQ, [[ (2 if (j==i+1 and i%2 or j==i-1 and i%2==0) else 1) if abs(j-i)==1 else 0 for j in range(matN)] for i in range(matN)])
    Q = A[1:matN-1, 1:matN-1]
    R = A[1:matN-1, [0,matN-1]]
    fundMat = (Q**0 - Q)^(-1)
    sol = fundMat*R
    return 2/3 + 1/3*sol[0,1]
```

Some explanation: Uses a Markov-Chain with top and bottom absorbing. Take one step to begin with, either you go straight to goal or to inner world where this Markov chain is then moving (starting from the second to top most node). Then the probability we want equals to $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3}p_n$ where $p_n$ is the probability of being absorbed to the bottom node starting from the second node.

The transition matrix is (for case $N=3$)

$$ \frac{1}{3} \left(\begin{array}{r|rrrr|r}
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}\right)
$$

and the fundamental matrix $(I-Q)^{-1}$ has an interesting form

$$ \frac{1}{2(3n-1)} \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
36 & 30 & 18 & 12 \\
30 & 45 & 27 & 18 \\
18 & 27 & 45 & 30 \\
12 & 18 & 30 & 36
\end{array}\right)
$$

Notice the first row (which we need in the calculation of the absorption probabilities from the aforementioned staring node) has the curios form that the last entry is always $12$ and then they increase as we go towards the start by jumps of $6$ and $12$. Perhaps this can be proved bruteforcishly and the general formula hence deduced.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

These graphs are equivalent to a cyclic graph on $2n$ vertices with alternating edge weights $2/3$ and $1/3$, thus the transition matrix has the form
$$\mathcal P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 &\ldots & 0 & 2/3 \\
1/3 & 0 & 2/3 & 0 &&& 0 \\
0 & 2/3 & 0 & 1/3 & \ddots && \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots && \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1/3 \\
2/3 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & 1/3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}_{\,2n \,\times\, 2n},$$
where row $i$ corresponds to the state of being at the $i^{\rm th}$ vertex from the top.  For the initial state vector $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \ldots & 0\end{bmatrix}$ we want the probability of reaching state $2n$ before returning to state $1$.  To find this, we can modify $\mathcal P$ so that the top and bottom vertices become absorbing, and the initial state vector begins at vertex $2$ with probability $1/3$ or is at the bottom vertex with probability $2/3$, effectively having taken the first step from the top vertex:

$$\mathcal P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\ldots & 0 & 0 \\
1/3 & 0 & 2/3 & 0 &&& 0 \\
0 & 2/3 & 0 & 1/3 & \ddots && \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots && \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1/3 \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}_{\,2n \,\times\, 2n}.$$  We can implement this in *Mathematica* as follows:

```
P[n_] := Flatten[Table[RotateRight[#, 2 k] & /@ (RotateLeft /@ 
      (Join[#, Table[0, {2 (n - 2)}]] & /@ {{2, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 2}})), 
      {k, 0, n - 1}], 1]

P2[n_] := ReplacePart[P[n]/3, {1 -> Prepend[Table[0, {2 n - 1}], 1], 
      2 n -> Append[Table[0, {2 n - 1}], 1]}]

R[n_] := DiscreteMarkovProcess[DiscreteMarkovProcess[P[n][[1]]/3, P2[n]]

Last /@ Table[MarkovProcessProperties[R[n], "ReachabilityProbability"], {n, 2, 10}]
```

The output for this is

$$\left\{\frac{4}{5},\frac{3}{4},\frac{8}{11},\frac{5}{7},\frac{12}{17},\frac{7}{10},\frac{16}{23},\frac{9}{13},\frac{20}{29}\right\}$$

which is sufficient to confirm that the desired probability is $2n/(3n-1)$.  Computing the reachability probability for $n = 100$ gives $200/299$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!